# Ajax post запрос передает null - asp.mvc core

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Пи попытке отправить акшэн получает null, хотя тот же посути код хорошо работает в asp.mvc 5

js

```js
const AjaxPOSTAsync = (url, object = null, method = "POST") => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.responseType = "json";
        xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
            resolve(xhr.response);
        });
        xhr.addEventListener("error", () => reject(xhr.statusText));
        const tmp = JSON.stringify(object);
        xhr.send(tmp);
    });
};

const btn01 = window.document.querySelector("#btn-01");
btn01.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    const dataSend = {
        language: "RU",
        table: {
            "Q1": "qweqweqe111Э",
            "Q2": "15"
        }
    };

    AjaxPOSTAsync(urlControlActionTest, dataSend).then((data) => {

        console.dir(dataSend);
        console.dir(data);
        btn01.textContent = data.Q1;

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

});
```

```
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            StringValues all = "*";
            var ctx = filterContext.HttpContext;
            var referer = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["referer"];
            var origin = ctx.Request.Headers["Origin"];
            var allowOrigin = origin.Count > 0 ? origin : all; //err StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(ctx3)
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowOrigin);
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
    public class ContentTypeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            //("Content-Type", "application/xml;charset=UTF-8");
            //("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            //("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class Table
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Id")]
        [Display(Name = "Q1")]
        public string Q1 { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Id")]
        [Display(Name = "Q2")]
        public string Q2 { get; set; }
    }
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowCrossSiteJson]
        [ContentType]
        public JsonResult Test(Table table, string language)
        {
            var altitudeString = Request.Query;
            if (table == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(table));
            }

            try
            {
                table.Q1 = language;
                var result = Json(table);
                return result;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { error = $"{ex.Message}" });
            }
        }
```

Маршруты

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Test", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Test}/{id?}");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

нужно точно указать порядок, у установить атрибут [FromBody], а инача "Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8" - работать не будет, и рпоблмема именно в нем

```
    const dataSend = {
        language: "RU",
        table: {
            "Q1": "qweqweqeqqqqqqq",
            "Q2": "15"
        }
    };

public JsonResult Test([FromBody]string language, [FromBody]Table table)
```